# Cassandra read performance interpreted

Tags: cassandra

I am performing some load tests for Cassandra for my master thesis. One of the tests to determine good values for the actual tests, tested how many measurements should be stored on each row (I call that timewidth).

To make the long story short, the results are definitely not what I expected. I run 2 sets of tests, one storing 100,000 values / row and one storing 10,000 values / row. For each of these two timewidths, I issued range queries with different ranges. By ranges I mean how many values are requested by each query. The ranges are: 3600 and 10000.

What I was expecting was that the 100,000 timewidth would perform better for the queries requesting many values (50,000 and 100,000) and the 10,000 timewidth better for the timewidth of 10,000. However in all cases the 100,000 timewidth performed better as can be seen on the tables bellow. The metrics for these were recorded on OpsCenter.

### Timewidth 100,000

Average number of ops / sec : 18167.56 (range 3600) | 5097.61 (range 10000)

Average latency / sec (ms)  : 1.24     (range 3600) | 2.16 (range 10000)

### Timewidth 10,000

Average number of ops / sec : 4186.35 (range 3600) | 587.78 (range 10000)

Average latency / sec (ms)  : 4.85 (range 3600)    | 48.63  (range 10000)

Could somebody who is familiar with Cassandra help me interpret these results? By the way the cluster I am running these tests again is a 6-node cluster, with quite powerful machines. The specs can be provided, but they are not that relevant I think. I am interested in why these two tests have so much performance difference. For the tests I am using a custom program using Hector. In total I run 60 instances of the client, which query Cassandra as fast as they can (it is not limited somehow). We are using Cassandra 1.2 datastax edition.

EDIT: Indeed the data schema used should have been mentioned my bad. Here is the information. First of all we are storing sensor data (timestamp-value pairs pretty much). On each row, the row key is an identifier for the row (e.g. actual measurements, simulation1, prediction1, etc), and the starting timestamp for this row. So the row key looks like . On each key value pair within this row we store the timestamp as the row key and the actual measurement value for the value part.

Besides these, we also keep a manual index row within the same column family. On that index row we store the identfier_meta (e.g. simulation1_meta) and on each key value pair of this row we store the starting timestamp as the column key and the row key containing the respective measurements as the value.

So for each read, we first determine which rows are involved (by querying the index) and then fetch the actual data that we want. As for the secondary indexes, no at the moment we are not using them. Again if you need any further information feel free to ask.

Comment: Could you provide the model of your column family? Are you using any composite keys? Any secondary indexes?